# allow-same-origin doesn't allow me to access properties of top object

Tags: javascript, html, cors, cross-domain, content-security-policy

I have the following code in the page `example1.com`:

```
<iframe src='//example2.com/embed.html' sandbox="allow-same-origin allow-modals allow-scripts allow-top-navigation allow-top-navigation-by-user-activation">
```

And I have the following code in my `embed.html`

```
<script>
    try { 
        document.write('top url: ' + top.location.href)
    }
catch (e) { 
document.write('error' + e);

}
</script>
```

I get the error:

```
SecurityError: Blocked a frame with origin "https://example2.com" from accessing a cross-origin frame.
```

I only want to get properties of `top` object and I use the tag `allow-same-origin` in my iframe code. Doesn't this tag allow me to run the iframe as same-origin? If not, why do we have that tag?

Answer (score 1):

`example1.com` and `example2.com` are a different domains therefore you have an issue with CORS (Cross-Origin Resource Sharing), but not with Content Security Policy. CORS allows direct access between the same domains or domain and its subdomain only.
You cannot get `top.location.href` property inside of cross origin iframe, but you can set it: `top.location.href = 'https://any_domain.com/path.html'` if `allow-top-navigation` presents in the `sandox` attribute or if `sandbox` is absent.

The `sandbox` attribute cannot help to bypass CORS restrictions, it only can imposes additional restrictions on the capabilities inside the iframe.

You can use [window.postMessage()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/postMessage) method for cross-origin communication between a page and an iframe embedded within it.